# How to bundle install private gem in github actions

Tags: ruby, rubygems, github-api, github-actions

I would like to run rspec on a gem (call it `priv_gem_a`) via github actions.

`priv_gem_a` depends on another gem that's in a private repo (call it `priv_gem_b`). However I cannot bundle install the `priv_gem_b` due to invalid permissions.

Error:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Fetching git@github.com:myorg/priv_gem_b
Host key verification failed.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Host key verification failed.
Retrying `git clone 'git@github.com:myorg/priv_gem_b' "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.6.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/priv_gem_b-886cdb130fe04681e92ab5365f7a1c690be8e62b" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` due to error (2/4): Bundler::Source::Git::GitCommandError Git error: command `git clone 'git@github.com:myorg/priv_gem_b' "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Ruby/2.6.3/x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/cache/bundler/git/priv_gem_b-886cdb130fe04681e92ab5365f7a1c690be8e62b" --bare --no-hardlinks --quiet` in directory /home/runner/work/priv_gem_a/priv_gem_a has failed.
```

I assume this is something to do with the runner not having access to differing private repos in the same org.

So I tried adding environment vars to my workflow file includes `GITHUB_TOKEN`s, but that doesn't work:

```
name: Test Code

on:
   push:
     branches:
     - master

jobs:
  test:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - name: Set up Ruby 2.6
      uses: actions/setup-ruby@v1
      with:
        ruby-version: 2.6.x
    - name: Install dependencies
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic
      run: |
        gem install bundler
        gem update bundler
        bundle install --without development --jobs 4 --retry 3
    - name: Test with RSpec
      run: |
        bundle exec rspec
```

Just a snippet from the Gemfile regarding this:

```
gem 'priv_gem_b', '>= 7.0.1', '< 8', git: 'git@github.com:my_org/priv_gem_b', branch: :master
```

Answer (score 15):

I'm fairly sure the default secret `GITHUB_TOKEN` in a repository is only scoped to that repository. You cannot use it to access other repositories.

Try using a `repo` scoped token instead. Create one at https://github.com/settings/tokens and then add it as a secret to the repository your workflow runs in. It will be under https://github.com/[username]/[repo]/settings/secrets

Use that secret in your workflow instead of `GITHUB_TOKEN`.

```
BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM: ${{ secrets.REPO_SCOPED_TOKEN }}:x-oauth-basic
```

Or, use the `x-access-token` method, which I think is preferable.

```
BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM: x-access-token:${{ secrets.REPO_SCOPED_TOKEN }}
```

Additionally, I think you need to change the reference to the private gem so that it uses HTTPS. The way that you are referencing it now means that it will try to use an SSH key instead of the token defined in `BUNDLE_GITHUB__COM`.

```
gem 'my_private_repo', git: 'https://github.com/username/my_private_repo.git'
```

Comment: Hey @peterevans, Thanks for the clarification on `GITHUB_TOKEN`, that makes sense now! However, I tried this method but it doesn't seem to be picking up my token (.../tokens has 'never used' next to the new one). The error is the same. Any ideas?

Comment: @StefanJCollier Have you also created a secret containing the token in the repository hosting the workflow?

Comment: Yup, I did do that. Is it possible to echo/print the key (just to prove it's being used)? I assume it will not fail if you use `${{ secrets.THIS_DOES_NOT_EXIST }}` given it's not defined

Comment: The way you are using the secret sounds correct to me. I believe I know what the problem is now. I've updated the answer with an additional step. Try changing the gem reference to use HTTPS.

Comment: @StefanJCollier Did you try the update I suggested?

Answer (score 4):

So my project contained a private gems which were being accessed using the ssh key.
We didn't want to change the Gemfile and access it through `https`, because that would involved changing deployment procedures.

We used this action [ssh-key-action](https://github.com/shimataro/ssh-key-action). We added the private ssh key in [github secrets](https://help.github.com/en/actions/configuring-and-managing-workflows/creating-and-storing-encrypted-secrets) for `SSH_KEY`.

```
- name: Install SSH keys
  uses: shimataro/ssh-key-action@v2
  with:
    key: ${{ secrets.SSH_KEY }}
    known_hosts: "Add known public keys of github here"

- name: Install gems # usual step to install the gems.
  run: |
    bundle config path vendor/bundle 
    bundle install --jobs 4 --retry 3
```

It worked seamlessly.

Note - Ensure that `key` parameter is **not** given hard coded private key. It won't work that way.